# Handling consumer cancellation notifications in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

We have followed the instructions in http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html to setup an active-active cluster with 3 nodes rabbit1, rabbit2 and rabbit3.
To create a mirrored queue, we are using x-ha-policy and to get consumer cancellation notifications we have put true for consumer_cancel_notify in clientProperties.
Now, we published messages to the queue with rabbit2 as master and had the consumer consume from  rabbit3. When rabbit2 is stopped, the consumer connected to rabbit3 is not getting a cancellation notification.

We are using rabbitmq 2.8.2-1 and our java consumer POC code is here - https://gist.github.com/2990146

Not sure what we are doing wrong. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Has anyone attempted to handle cancel notifications with  php-amqplib?

Answer (score 2):

Line #22 of your gist is a problem.  consumer_cancel_notify needs to be in the capabilities table in clientProperties rather than a top-level key.

```
clientProperties.put("consumer_cancel_notify", Boolean.valueOf(true));
```

> AMQP 0-9-1 clients don't by default expect to receive basic.cancel
>   methods from the broker asynchronously, and so in order to enable this
>   behaviour, the client must present a **capabilities table** in its
>   **client-properties** in which there is a key **consumer_cancel_notify** and a
>   boolean value true. See the capabilities section for further details
>   on this.
>   http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html#consumer-cancel-notify

Handwaving pseudo-java (please edit this answer after testing)

```
Map<String, Object> clientProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> clientCapabilities = new HashMap<String, Object>();
clientCapabilities.put("consumer_cancel_notify", Boolean.valueOf(true));
clientProperties.put("capabilities", clientCapabilities);
```

As for your original question, "Has anyone attempted to handle cancel notifications with php-amqplib?" it looks like the answer is a firm "maybe" ==> 
http://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/11cynv8zkz/active-active-implementation-in-php

Comment: Can you please tell me where to specify this option for .NET client?

Comment: @Pritam , I haven't used .NET, but it looks like you would set it as a sub dictionary on the `capabilities` key of the the `IDictionary clientProperties`  that you pass to `ConnectionStartOK`.  https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.4.3/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.4.3-user-guide.pdf